# ASPX C# How do I download Files where the user wants them?

Tags: c#, asp.net, download

I am trying to develop a web page which will allow users to download to the Directory of there Choice.  In my search to find away to do this, I had found that you can't use "FolderBrowserDialog".  I am also finding that the examples online will only search the websrver directeory path and not the local machine.  Is there anyway to get the Directory Path?  I have the code to FTP the File Down, I just have to replace the code for "FolderBrowserDialog".

Comment: I dont think is possible to access user directory structure on server

Comment: Downloading a file is a browser function. Any browser will prompt a dialog similar to a SaveFileDialog when a user downloads a file. Some browsers may have a default path for downloads (ie GoogleChrome). You just have to write some code to start the download - tmt - Write the requested file to the response stream (see: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpresponse.writefile(v=vs.71).aspx ) - hth

Answer (score 6):

This isn't really up to you as a website, it's really the browsers job to store where they want files downloaded to. There is a pretty necessary separation between the website and client machine going on here.

Answer (score 0):

In a web application you can't arbitrarily read or write stuff on the user's computer. That would be a gaping security hole, so it just can't be done. The 'Save As' dialog is something that happens entirely client-side. Your control over the download process ends as soon as you set the MIME type and send the file data away.

Comment: I am using FTP and I just need to get the path of where they want it to go.  Once i have the path i think I will be good, but I want something other than a textbox to get the path.

Comment: If you're using FTP, how is that related to ASPX pages? Please clarify what you're trying to do.

Comment: On my page I have everything for accessing our FTP site, Currently I can show the files, Upload Files and Delete.  All with C# and my ASPX interface.  Now trying to do the download without having to say please paste your download location into this textbox.  they gave us an upload control, but no download control to just collect a path name.

Comment: Even if you 'have the path' you will not be able to write the file to the client's computer under an arbitrary path... you just can't do that. As said before, all you can do is send the file with the appropriate headers, and that will trigger the 'Save As' dialog in the browser, and that's it.

Answer (score 0):

Browsers wont usually let you to choose  location for individual download. you can change your browser settings to update the download folder. If you want to have this in your webpage, you probably need to have an activex control. this activex control can show the directories in the client machine so that user can select those. You need to write code to download the file to that location using the WebClient.DownloadFile method.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ez801hhe.aspx

Don't expect this activex control works with all your users.Browsers usually block activex control or prompt the user (if the setting is like that).